# Register-SPWorkflowService in SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, powershell, workflow-manager

When I am using management shell(admin) the error "SPWorkflowService is not register with cmdlet" is showing up.

Is it possible to configure SP Workflow Manager  in SP Foundation 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is **no** option to use SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows in SharePoint Foundation. It is **only available in SharePoint Server** (Standard and Enterprise).

Check the comparison here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise